# How to compile a single C# class file to .exe using the command-line?

Tags: c#, class, cmd, command-line, compilation

I am having trouble trying to compile a single class file to a executable. This is just a .cs file on its own with a simple hello world like so

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq;


namespace Q3J1G0HFP7EXE58
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "First Attempt";
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

How would I, from the command line compile this into a .exe file? Or what process would I need to do in order to get it into a .exe file (all from command like pref). 3rd party programs are a welcome suggestion, I have tried using the csc method but it will not work with just a class file.

It's going to be auto generated code which I then want to compile as a separate program from the one which wrote the code to file. Writing to executable is suppose to be a completely automated process but compiling is becoming an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was just being blind, I got it to work.

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -out:dir\test.exe dir\Test.cs
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the duplicated `using System.Linq` else it can't compile.

Next if you have installed Visual Studio, and if you have saved for example the file to `Program.cs` you can compile with that from the command line from the .cs file folder:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe" Program.cs
```

This path is for Visual Studio 2017.

Replace the `csc.exe` path by what you have on your disk.

If you have not Visual Studio, you can use for example:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

Replace the path by what you have on the disk.

Here is the documentation for command line arguments:

[Command-line build with csc.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe)